# Tag score for suggested synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, privileges

In order to suggest a synonym, you need a total answer score of 5 to make that suggestion.

Is that a score of 5 in the tag you're looking at, or in the tag you're suggesting for the synonym?

For instance, and I did this purely for display purposes, in the below example do I need a score of 5 in [area-51](/questions/tagged/area-51), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or both?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need that score  only in the "from" tag, the tag that is being synonymed to something else. In this case, [area-51](/questions/tagged/area-51).

Comment: I was thinking __area51__ was the _to_ tag here. I also get confused by the synonyming nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

[source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/synonyms)

Comment: I'm not understanding if it's on the tag or the suggested synonym.  Pardon my stupidity, it's New Years Day after all.  :o)

Comment: On the tag :-D.

Comment: So, in my above example, I need to have a 5 score **only** in the area-51 tag?

Comment: Well you cannot suggest a synonym of a tag to another one that already exists. but yes.

Comment: @qwertynl huh?  That's the whole purpose of synonyms